# Visual Studio Autodeploy - The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error NU1102

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, telerik, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm getting this error when I upgraded to Telerik 2019.1.220 and trying to autodeploy to IIS.

(It works fine on my workstation but gives this error on autodeploy)

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1102: Unable to
>   find package Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core with version (>= 2019.1.220) -
>   Found 3 version(s) in 0a59f170-36b0-42ba-bd72-49a72d6553d6 [ Nearest
>   version: 2018.2.620 ] - Found 1 version(s) in NuGetOrg [ Nearest
>   version: 2016.3.914 ] Errors in D:\a\1\s\IT.Web\IT.Web.csproj
>   NU1102: Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core with version
>   (>= 2019.1.220) - Found 3 version(s) in
>   0a59f170-36b0-42ba-bd72-49a72d6553d6 [ Nearest version: 2018.2.620 ] -
>   Found 1 version(s) in NuGetOrg [ Nearest version: 2016.3.914 ])
>
> Packages failed to restore

[image]

It looks like Nuget has 2019.1.220: https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoUICore/

I've installed 2019.1.220 directly on the server with the telerik downloader but still no luck. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Visual studio error output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core is distributed through a private NuGet feed. Therefore, in order to be able to successfully restore the package:

1) If Azure DevOps is used for managing the packages, the Telerik private Feed has to be correctly set up in Azure. Refer to the following resources that might be of help for configuring the feed:

- [Set Up Telerik Private NuGet Feed for Azure.](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/knowledge-base/setup-private-nuget-feed-azure)
- [Azure DevOps Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-nav)

2) If you would like to manually connect to the private Feed and restore the package follow this documentation article:

- [Telerik Private NuGet Feed.](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/nuget-install#the-telerik-private-nuget-feed)